# Сравнение html кода страниц на схожесть %

Tags: php, mysql, парсер

Есть некий парсер на php который собирает данные с сайтов. Задача сравнить исходные коды анализируемых сайтов на схожесть в %, для поиска сайтов сделанных по одному шаблону.

**В данный момент реализовал так:**
Сохраняю в базу исходный код каждой каждого сайта и сравниваю со всеми имеющимися с помощью стандартной функции similar_text. С задачей она справляется и точность достаточно высокая, *НО!* ввиду сложности алгоритма этой функции она очень долго работает и "отжирает" весь процессор, соответственно когда сайтов стало больше 1000, время работы и нагрузка на сервер сильно увеличились.
**Вопрос:**
Существуют ли упрощенные реализации similar_text() на php или какие-то другие методы, или есть ли возможность сделать такое сравнение сразу в mysql?
 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

В [документации](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.similar-text.php) говорится, что `similar_text` работает за O(n<sup>3</sup>).

[Расстояние Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0) ([`levenshtein`](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.levenshtein.php)) работает за O(n<sup>2</sup>), что существенно быстрее, но может быть по-прежнему недостаточно быстро. Думаю, гораздо эффективнее будет применить расстояние Левенштейна не на символах, а на токенах, только это придётся реализовать самостоятельно. Возможно даже, что это будет уже достаточно быстро, а может и нет.